# Calling a Perl Script from a C Script, Sorting Text File

Tags: c, perl, sorting, file-io

I'm making a program that displays a menu and offers to sort a file using multiple different languages.  Currently I have a piece of code that will take in a text file, sort it, and output it to a new text file:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>

#define MAXNAMELEN 100
#define MAXLINELEN 100
#define MAXITEMS 1000

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    FILE * infile, * outfile;
    // Statically allocated -- dastardly!
    char name[MAXNAMELEN];
    char line[MAXLINELEN];
    char lines[MAXITEMS][MAXLINELEN];
    int i, items = 0;

    printf("Enter a source filename: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
    name[strlen(name)-1] = '\0'; // strip newline
    // No error checking -- ANYWHERE -- dastardly!
    infile = fopen(name, "r");
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), infile)) {
            strcpy(lines[items], line);
            items++;
    }

    qsort(lines, items, MAXLINELEN, strcmp);

    printf("Enter a destination filename: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
    name[strlen(name)-1] = '\0'; // strip newline
    outfile = fopen(name, "w");
    for (i=0; i<items; i++) {
        fputs(lines[i], outfile);
    }

    fclose(infile);
    fclose(outfile);
}
```

I have the menu part down, but I'm having trouble implementing a way to call a Perl script to sort the file.  I want the C program to do the writes to the output file, but the Perl Script to sort it.  How can this be achieved? Nasty embedding is what I've found so far..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe a process with `popen` and then get the output with `fgets`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *mode);
int pclose(FILE *stream);

int main(void)
{
    FILE *cmd;
    char result[1024];

    cmd = popen("myperlscript myparams", "r");
    if (cmd == NULL) {
        perror("popen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (fgets(result, sizeof(result), cmd)) {
        printf("%s", result);
    }
    pclose(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what's going on here?  The file I'm reading is just a list of first names. So my sorting perl script is called with popen, and this reads the result of that script?

Comment: So would my perl script have to return/output the sorted array then? I'm confused as to what would be read.

Comment: Yes, print (to stdout) from your perl script